# How to get the SQL query from a file in SSIS

Tags: sql, xml, ssis, configuration-files

I'm new to SSIS. I have a DataBase from which i'm getting the data. Suppose DB is the source and destination may be anything. (I tried DB to Excel and it worked fine)

In the source i have a custom query to get the data. I have written that in the properties.

Now i want to change it. I want to put it in some configuration file (xml file). i.e., i want to 
get the query of the source from the xml file. How can i do this?

I'm a complete newbie trying the things. So please give your answer specifically.

**UPDATE**:

This is my package

[image]

I double clicked the OLE DB source. Now This is what i written there

[image]

I want to put the query (select id, age from emp where exp > 4), in a configuration(xml) file.

Comment: would you want to deployee the package or something else. actually i didn't get you what would you asking for would you elaborate more.

Comment: Ya its a package. I want to deploy.
Source      : DB
Destination : Excel

I connected them. Now the data in the database will be exported to Excel.

Instead of th whole data i want to export only part of the data (say employee details who have experience more than 4 years.) For that i need to write a custom query.

My requirement is, i want to place that query in a configuration file(xml file). How can i do this?

Comment: i want to know about what do you want to put in configuration file.

Comment: I want to put the source table query in the configuration file. Am i clear?

Comment: @user3864233 Please see the update in the post

Comment: There is no need to put query in configuration file. you just create a procedure and execute that procedure in oledb source. would you want to change the query then just go on the procedure and simply alter it

Comment: @user3864233 Isn't there a way to ge the query from a file?

Comment: Yes. Do some research on _Expressions_ and _Configurations_. You can set the value of the source query at run time using a configuration but the columns must be **IDENTICAL**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a package level variable for your query:
   [image: Create a package level variable for your query]
2. Change your source editor to use SQL command from variable (with appropriate variable) instead of SQL command:
   [image]
3. Go to the SSIS menu and click "Package Configurations..." then click the checkbox to Enable package configurations, then click the "Add..." button.
   [image]

... By default, it uses an XML Configuration file, which is probably easiest to work with. Specify a filename - the file extension is .dtsConfig. If the file doesn't exist on your machine, it will create one for you. Click Next.

4. Find your Variable, find the Value property for the variable, and check the box for it. Click Next.
   [image]
5. Choose a name for your configuration. Click Done, then click Close in the Package configuration list, making a note of where on your file system you saved your configuration file.
6. Find the configuration file on your file system. Right-click and edit with an XML editor as needed. 
   [image]